# 301 redirect ?___store=default

Tags: apache, magento, redirect

I need to make 301 redirection for all urls that have this kind of ending in them:

?___store=default&___from_store=com

For example:

301 FROM URL

https://www.example.com/page.html?___store=default&___from_store=com

TO:

https://www.example.com/page.html?___store=default_migrated&___from_store=com

Server has Apache in it and Magento 2 is the CMS I have running there. If more details are needed I'm happy to provide them.

Comment: So you want to modify some server?  One you have provided absolutely no information about?

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a `RewriteRule` in apache for this. Basically you would just need to check the `%{QUERY_STRING}` server variable to see if it matches the query string that is exactly "?___store=default&___from_store=com" (you can change it to be a bit less strict in the matching with a regex if needed).

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^___store=default&___from_store=com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1?___store=default_migrated&___from_store=com [L,R=301]
```

You can read more about Apache RewriteRules [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).